# Python: Class definition without arguments

Tags: python

Sorry for the noob question about classes. I'm trying to assign a soap client to a variable inside a class function and then access that variable in other class functions. I don't have any arguments to pass to the `setup_client()` function.

In the following example code, how do I make `self.client` accessible outside `setup_client()` so that I can use it in `use_client()`, and ditto making `self.response` available outside `use_client()`

```
class soap_call(self):
    def __init__(self):
        # What goes here?
        self.client = # what?
        self.response = # what?

    def setup_client(self):
        credentials = {'username': 'stuff', 'password': 'stuff'}
        url = 'stuff'
        t = HttpAuthenticated(**credentials)
        self.client = suds.client.Client(url, transport=t)

    def use_client(self):
        self.response = self.client.service.whatever
        print self.response
```

I quickly realized that if I add an optional client argument `(self, client=None)` to the class definition and include `self.client = client`, then I get a None type error when trying to use it in my functions.

I realize I just have a lack of understanding of classes. I've done some general reading up on classes but haven't come across any specific examples that describe what I'm dealing with.

Comment: Is the use of `self` as the base class for `soap_call` a typo?

Comment: @chepner No, it's jut my general lack of understanding, and that my IDE automatically added (self) to soap_call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with None in both cases because logically speaking, none of them exists at the time of object instantiation. It also allows you to do some sanity checking of your logic, e.g.

```
class SoapCall(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = None
        self.response = None

    def setup_client(self):
        credentials = {'username': 'stuff', 'password': 'stuff'}
        url = 'stuff'
        t = HttpAuthenticated(**credentials)
        if self.client is None:
            self.client = suds.client.Client(url, transport=t)

    def use_client(self):
        if self.client is None:
            self.client = self.setup_client()

        self.response = self.client.service.whatever
        print self.response
```

Comment: Incidentally, I was calling my functions incorrectly, but thank you for this. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to leave the client unspecified when you first create the instance, but then you need to be sure to call `setup_client` before you call `use_client`.

Comment: I tried that, which is the problem. self.client is unavailable to use_client in the current code.

Comment: Yes, which is why I said you have to call `setup_client` *before* you call `use_client`. What does it mean to call `use_client` before you have  client defined?